# List of Objects sent to the controller from jQuery are always null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

So this is my class that of my model:

```
[Table("Question", Schema = "trs")]
public class Question
{

    [Key]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TranType")]
    [Required]
    public int TranTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Company")]

    [Required]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(300)]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("QuestionType")]
    public int QTypeId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdateUserId { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }

    public TranType TranType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Answer> Answer { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Grading> Grading { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller action, for now it is doing nothing because I need to get the values first which are the problem:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class QuestionController : Controller
{
    readonly IQuestionRepository questionRepository;
    readonly ICompanyRepository companyRepository;

    public QuestionController(IQuestionRepository qRepository, ICompanyRepository cpnRepository)
    {

        questionRepository = qRepository;
        companyRepository = cpnRepository;

    }
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save([FromBody] List<Question> qView)
    {
        return View(qView);
    }
}
```

Now I have tried also:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Save(List<Question> qView)
 {
        return View(qView);
 }
```

In both cases I have problems; in the first option (with [FromBody]) qView is null; and in option 2 (without [FromBody]) qView is not null but the List is empty (Count == 0).

Here is the Code to generate the JSON data:

```
function Send()
{ 
    var qCounter = parseInt($('#quesCounter').val());
    var listQuestion = [];
    var qView = {};
    qView.Questions = listQuestion;
    for (i = 1; i <= qCounter; i++)
    {
        var question = {};
        var listAnswer = [];
        question.Answers = listAnswer;

        var anCounter = parseInt($('#qtCounter' + i).val());
        var qText = $('#qtText' + i).val();
        var qType = $('#qType' + i).val();

        question["Text"] = qText;
        question["QTypeId"] = qType;

       for (j = 1; j <= anCounter; j++)
        { 
            var answer = {};

            var aText = $('#anText' + i.toString() + j.toString()).val();
            var aCorrect = "";

            if ($('#anCorrect' + i.toString() + j.toString()).prop('checked')) {
                aCorrect = "yes";
            }
            else {
                aCorrect = "no";
            }
            answer["Text"] = aText;
            answer["IsCorrect"] = aCorrect;
            question.Answers.push(answer);
        }

        qView.Questions.push(question);
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Save", // the method we are calling
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(qView),
        //data: JSON.stringify({ 'qView': qView }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert('Yay! It worked!');
            // Or if you are returning something
            alert('I returned... ' + result.WhateverIsReturning);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Oh no :(');
        }
    });
}
```

I have no clue what is wrong.

Please any idea where is my issue?

Comment: in your ajax call, try to use the following `data: { 'qView': qView }`

Comment: Thanks' but I did that already and the issue is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys so the issue was the way I was calling the the ajax method in the wrong way and some of the properties in the mapping on the client side; I fixed by running the method this way:

```
 function Send()
{ 
    var qCounter = parseInt($('#quesCounter').val());
    var listQuestion = [];

    for (i = 1; i <= qCounter; i++)
    {
        var question = {};
        var listAnswer = [];
        question.Answer = listAnswer; //Second problem was here because I was calling here the array Answers when the List<Answer> property on the server side was called Answer.

        var anCounter = parseInt($('#qtCounter' + i).val());
        var qText = $('#qtText' + i).val();
        var qType = $('#qType' + i).val();

        question["Text"] = qText;
        question["QTypeId"] = parseInt(qType);// first problem was here because the property on the Server side was integer and I was sending string.

       for (j = 1; j <= anCounter; j++)
        { 
            var answer = {};

            var aText = $('#anText' + i.toString() + j.toString()).val();
            var aCorrect = "";

            if ($('#anCorrect' + i.toString() + j.toString()).prop('checked')) {
                aCorrect = 1; //third problem was here because true/yes was not recognize so I had to change to 1/0;.
            }
            else {
                aCorrect = 0; //same as above (third problem).
            }
            answer["Text"] = aText;
            answer["IsCorrect"] = aCorrect;
            question.Answer.push(answer);
        }

        listQuestion.push(question);
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Save", // the method we are calling
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(listQuestion),
        success: function (result) {
            alert('worked');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Something failed');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the **contentType** to `application/json` and then you **stringify** your data before sent? You've just contradicted yourself.

You're basically saying: Server, I am sending you a JSON object. But then since you stringify the object, the Server will only see a string. That's why the server wouldn't match the data to your model.

### My 2 cents

1. As long as the JavaScript object / JSON you construct on client-side matches the model you have in the parameter of your controller, you don't need to specify `contentType` and `[FromBody]` - to keep things simply. MVC is smart enough to do the binding for you. You don't even need to use lowercase in your C# model for the properties. You can even use `true/false` for boolean, as long as the matching property in C# model is defined as `bool`.
2. Don't use your domain/data model on your view/page. Create a separate model (called view model) and put only what you need to display/use on the view/page there. You don't want to expose what you have in the database to the whole world.
3. Use **camelCase** for variables and functions please in JavaScript. The way you declared your `function Send()`, `qView.Questions =` and `question.Answers.push(answer);` just made me crazy :p.

### Code Example

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',

    // Use HTML helper to generate the link instead of hardcode.
    // HTML helper will take care the host, port, and more for you.
    url: '@Url.Action("save", "question", new { area = "" })',

    // You usually don't need to specify the contentType.
    // The default 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' works well for 
    // JSON objects.
    //contentType: "application/json",

    // You don't need to stringify the data
    data: { qView: qView },
    //data: JSON.stringify({ 'qView': qView }),

    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert('Yay! It worked!');
        // Or if you are returning something
        alert('I returned... ' + result.WhateverIsReturning);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert('Oh no :(');
    }
})
// I would use .done() here instead of success and error() but 
// this is just personal taste.
;
```